# ibuffer-expert not working

Tags: hooks, ibuffer

I want to make my ibuffer not to be pompted.

So it is my config for ibuffer

```
(setq ibuffer-expert t) ;; disable prompt when deleting modified buffer.
(add-hook 'ibuffer-hook (lambda ()
              (ibuffer-auto-mode 1) ;; keeps ibuffer list up to date
              (setq ibuffer-show-empty-filter-groups nil) ;; don't show empty group
              (ibuffer-vc-set-filter-groups-by-vc-root)
              (ibuffer-do-sort-by-recency)))
```

first line of it I setted ibuffer export to true.
But I open ibuffer then I execute to kill modified buffer or special buffer like multi-term. It is still asked to prompt.

What is problem?

Answer (score 2):

> I open ibuffer then I execute to kill modified buffer or special buffer like multi-term. It is still asked to prompt.

It is not `ibuffer` that is prompting you in these cases.

Your multi-term buffer will be running a process so, when ibuffer tries to kill that buffer, Emacs will ask if you are sure you want to kill the process.

Similarly, when ibuffer tries to kill a modified buffer which is visiting a file, Emacs will ask if you are sure you want to do that, as you will lose your modifications.

---

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `kill-buffer` tells us:

> The functions in ‘kill-buffer-query-functions’ are called with the
>   buffer to be killed as the current buffer.  If any of them returns nil,
>   the buffer is not killed.  The hook ‘kill-buffer-hook’ is run before the
>   buffer is actually killed.  The buffer being killed will be current
>   while the hook is running.  Functions called by any of these hooks are
>   supposed to not change the current buffer.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `kill-buffer-query-functions` shows that it contains the function `process-kill-buffer-query-function` which will "Ask before killing a buffer that has a running process."

If you're really sure you want to, you can disable that with:

```el
(remove-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'process-kill-buffer-query-function)
```

Note that this doesn't *only* affect ibuffer.  Anything that kills a buffer is affected.

---

To kill a *modified* file-visiting buffer without being prompted, you may need to write a `kill-buffer-query-functions` function which sets the buffer as un-modified.  I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: but ibuffer-expert said that `If non-nil, Don't ask for confirmation of "dangerous" operations.`

Comment: The meaning of `ibuffer-expert` is confined to ibuffer's *own* behaviours -- it doesn't mean that *other* parts of Emacs will stop prompting you.  In your examples, `ibuffer` is not asking you to confirm anything.  I can see why you interpreted the description the way you did, but I'm afraid it doesn't actually do what you thought it did.

Comment: From what I can see, the "dangerous" ibuffer operations are: `ibuffer-do-shell-command-pipe-replace`, `ibuffer-do-revert`, `ibuffer-do-delete`, `ibuffer-do-kill-on-deletion-marks`.  If you are not an expert, then ibuffer itself will ask you to confirm those operations.